# Why did my app crash when using cloudkit?

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

When I try to load data from iCloud using Swift, the app crashes with this error. Why is that? I can't seem to find the bug?

[image]

**Code:**

```
func LoadEvents() {

        let predicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query:CKQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "Data", predicate: predicate)
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

        if let database = self.publicDatabase {

            database.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: { (records:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) in

                if error != nil {
                    self.alert("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)", Message: "Make sure iCloud is turned on and you are connected to the internet")   
                } else {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.EventsArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                        for record in records {
                            let usernameRecord:CKRecord = record as CKRecord     
                            self.EventsArray.insert(usernameRecord.objectForKey("Events") as String, atIndex: 0)
                            println("1")
                        }

                        //update data
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            })        
        }
}
```

Comment: If only the console told you what the problem was, huh ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The record that you are reading probably does not have a field named Events. So the objectForKey will return nil which cannot be casted to string. You could solve this by using `as? String` or use:

```
if let event = usernameRecord.objectForKey("Events") as? String{
    self.EventsArray.insert(event, atIndex: 0)
}
```